# Object has no attribute error "l" but the attribute is there

Tags: python, list, loops, class, object

```
from dateutil import parser 

#define list
telf = []
addf = []
datef = []
namef = [] 

#create class
class linefilter:   

    def __init__ (self, l):
        self.l = l 

    def checkdate(self):
        for w in self.l:
            w = bool(parser.parse(w))
            if w:
                return w 

    def istel(self): 
        w = 'tel:'
        return (' ' + w + ' ') in (' ' + self.l + ' ') 

    def hasnum(self): 
        return any(char.isdigit() for char in self.l)

    def checkaddr(self): 
        for w in self.l:
            for w in ['st', 'rd', 'suite', 'ave', 'pl', 'ln', 'apt', 'fl']:
                return (' ' + w + ' ') in (' ' + self.l + ' ') 
   
    def chekcity(self):
        if hasnum(self.l):
            for w in self.l:
                w = bool(re.match(r"[A-Z][A-Z]" "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"))
                return w

#Pass_line_to_class
mlist = ['larry petterio', 'llc', '10345 RIXI AVE APT 13', 'NYC, NY 29321', '12/13/1789', 'tel: 756.345.5280']

for l in mlist:
    
    if linefilter.hasnum(l) is False:
        namef.append(l)
    if linefilter.istel(l):
        telf.append(l)
    if linefilter.checkaddr(l):
        addf.append(l)
    if linefilter.checkcity(l):
        cityf.append(l)
```

I am attempting to grab each item in a list and run a specific method based on requirements.

i can see the output of print(l) but i get error when passing "l" to class:

AttributeError: 'str' has no attribute 'l'

Comment: Your forgot to instantiate the class.  `linefilter` is a class, not an instance of a class.  The normal thing to do would be to rename it to `LineFilter`, then do `linefilter = LineFilter()` to create an instance of the class.

Comment: @TomKarzes That's partly true. However, the functions hasnum, istel etc., do not take any parameters apart from the implicit *self*

Comment: If you don't plan to instantiate an instance of your class you could decorate your functions with @staticmethod and remove *self*

Comment: The way you have set up your code, you will need to create this instance at the start of each iteration with the line as input to the constructor: `linefilter = LineFilter(l)`. The line will then not be needed as an input to the methods you are calling afterwards.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I was able to resolve issue.